# how to apply a style to an image

Tags: css, html

On this page, I have an image with a glossy effect in a div below the image.

http://www.joelin.org/home2.html

I basically want to move the glossy effect on top of the image. I tried

1) adding the style directly to the img tag, no effect
2) creating a div around the image, putting the glossy div in it (but the glossy div ended up being below the image)

any other thoughts?

Comment: Use absolute positioned layers with z-index inside a relative positioned wrapper. But the image you want above the other won't stretch though. Start with this search, https://www.google.se/search?q=absolute+relative+positioning+css&sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Just using the styles on the `div` on the `img` should work. You could try adding `display:block` if it doesn't work, but I think image tags are blocks by default. All of the styles specified are compatible with images so there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Make the image a background to the div.

Comment: i tried the background image thing, but the resulting image came out too big and cropped when i specified a div width/height...

Comment: If you can't resize your images appropriately on the server (I would) you can use the [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) property on modern browsers to resize a background image. But for older browsers, you'll need to use a real `<img>` tag and the approach that @Henrik suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it something like this http://dabblet.com/gist/3610138 that you're looking to achieve?

HTML:

```
<a href='#' class='img-wrapper'>
    <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2012-10-a-web.jpg'>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.img-wrapper, .img-wrapper img {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 13em;
    height: 8em;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
.img-wrapper:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1em 0 0 rgba(192, 192, 192, .5);
    pointer-events: none; /* so that you can get image from right-click menu
                                won't work in IE and Opera */
    content: '';
}
```

If you don't need the img tag and you can have the image as a background image, then it gets easier. Just one element:

```
<div class='glossy'></div>
```

and just this CSS:

```
.glossy {
    width: 13em;
    height: 8em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(192, 192, 192, .5) 12.5%, transparent 12.5%),
        radial-gradient(100% 100%, transparent 71%, rgba(192, 192, 192, .5) 71%) 
            no-repeat 0 1em,
        radial-gradient(0% 100%, transparent 71%, rgba(192, 192, 192, .5) 71%) 
            no-repeat 100% 1em,
        url(http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2012-10-a-web.jpg);
    background-size: 1px 100%, 1em 1em, 1em 1em, cover;
}
```

Comment: it did it! wow, i would not have been able to figure out all that... thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using absolute positioning for the div to lay it over top the image. You'll need to use z-index to layer properly as well. Try something like this:

```
.imageClass
{
    z-index: 1;
}

.glossyDiv
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 999px;
    left: 999px;
    z-index: 5;
    /* you'll need to figure out where your image sits in relation to the
    top and left of the screen, replace the 999s with the correct values */
}
```

That should get the div over the image. You can alter this so that the div is positioned relative to its container if that's how you've got your HTML set up.

The z-index controls how elements are layered/stacked, so setting the div to a higher index brings it closer to the "front" of the screen and lower numbers set it to the back. Note that z-index will only work on "positioned" elements [source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Impractical and unnecessarily complex to locate the absolute position of each image. (Requires JS, which is not needed in general to solve this problem.)

Comment: i learned something about positioning here..thx (went with the other solution)